# Conditions under which the power curve is not smooth or continuous in Hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

Not sure if this is a valid question.

I was wondering if there is are good answers to this question:

> Under what conditions is the power curve not smooth or continuous in Hypothesis testing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When the test involved is a permutation test the number of possible permutations is limited and so the power curve has to have steps.

Answer (score 1):

Where the parameter-space is discontinuous?

e.g. Hypothesis test of a parameter for a hypergeometric.